# p5.js: how to draw with coordinates from face-api.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to retrieve the 68 face landmarks in face-api.js (real-time webcam) and using these points to draw `curveVertex()` in p5.js. I can retrieve the landmarks so far but I'm having trouble using it in `draw()`.

I'm using this code for face detection from https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Face-Detection-JavaScript and I've tried to add some p5.js code in there:

```js
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
  navigator.getUserMedia({
      video: {}
    },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )

}

video.addEventListener('playing', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = {
    width: video.width,
    height: video.height
  }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)

  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks()
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
    landmarks = await faceapi.detectFaceLandmarks(video)
    landmarkPositions = landmarks.positions
    // console.log(landmarkPositions[0]);

  }, 100)

})

//p5.js
function setup() {
  var myCanvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
      myCanvas.parent("overlay");
  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  // background(0);
  stroke(255);
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(4);

  beginShape();
  //test
  curveVertex(100, 200);
  curveVertex(150, 50);
  curveVertex(250, 60);
  curveVertex(300, 200);
  curveVertex(300, 200);
  //get landmark positions
  curveVertex(landmarkPositions[0]);
  // curveVertex(landmarkPositions[1]),
  // curveVertex(landmarkPositions[2]),
  // curveVertex(landmarkPositions[3])

  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    canvas {
      position: absolute;
    }

    #overlay{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
<video id="video" width="720" height="560" autoplay muted></video>
```

How can I use `landmarkPositions` in `curveVertex()` in real time?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with `beginShape()`/`curveVertex()`/`endShape()`, it should (in theory) be just a matter of iterating through each landmark position and passing the x,y coordinates to draw.

Currently you seem to pass the landmark directly: `curveVertex(landmarkPositions[0]);` while [`curveVertex()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curveVertex) requires x, y coordinates.

Something like should work:

`curveVertex(landmarkPositions[0].x, landmarkPositions[0].y);` because according to the [face-api documentation](https://justadudewhohacks.github.io/face-api.js/docs/classes/point.html) a `Point` has `x,y` properties

You could use a for loop to iterate over each point:

```
beginShape();
for(let i = 0 ; i < landmarkPositions.length; i++){
  //get landmark position
  let position = landmarkPositions[i];
  curveVertex(position.x, position.y);
}
endShape(CLOSE);
```

Additionally notice that [`FaceLandmark68`](https://justadudewhohacks.github.io/face-api.js/docs/classes/facelandmarks68.html) on top of the `positions` array also comes with convenience functions such as:

- `getJawOutline()`
- `getLeftEye()`
- `getLeftEyeBrow()`
- `getMouth()`
- `getNose()`
- `getRightEye()`
- `getRightEyeBrow()`

I'm guessing you want to experiment with curves instead of lines ?
If you did simply want to render the landmark lines [face-api can do that too](https://justadudewhohacks.github.io/face-api.js/docs/index.html#live-demos). This is their example snippet:

```
const detectionsWithLandmarks = await faceapi
  .detectAllFaces(input)
  .withFaceLandmarks()

// resize the detected boxes and landmarks in case your displayed image has a different size then the original
const detectionsWithLandmarksForSize = faceapi.resizeResults(detectionsWithLandmarks, { width: input.width, height: input.height })
// draw them into a canvas
const canvas = document.getElementById('overlay')
canvas.width = input.width
canvas.height = input.height
faceapi.drawLandmarks(canvas, detectionsWithLandmarks, { drawLines: true })
```

This line in particular is what your after: `faceapi.drawLandmarks(canvas, detectionsWithLandmarks, { drawLines: true })`

If you already store the p5.js canvas as `myCanvas`, simply pass `myCanvas.elt` to get p5.js HTML `<canvas/>` element to faceapi

**Update:**

Here's a snippet with the notes mentioned in comments: essentially using p5.js  and  along with faceapi

Unfortunately I can't easily upload the models and faceapi.js to stackoverflow snippets nor the online p5.js editor, however you should be able to use this script in your copy of Face-Detection-JavaScript:

```
// p5.js canvas and it's HTML <canvas/> element
let p5Canvas;
let p5CanvasElement;
// p5.js capture and it's HTML <video/> element
let capture;
let captureElement;
// store dimenions formatted for faceapi
let displaySize;

function setup(){
  // create canvas (same size as default camera)..and to it's HTML element (.elt)
  p5Canvas = createCanvas(640, 480);
  p5CanvasElement = p5Canvas.elt;
  // create capture and reference it's HTML element (.elt)
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  captureElement = capture.elt;
  // hide video
  capture.hide();
  // setup faceapi dimensions
  displaySize = { width: width, height: height };
  faceapi.matchDimensions(p5Canvas, displaySize);

  // optional: match setInterval(..., 100) -> 10fps from the example
  frameRate(10);
  noFill();
  // trigger model loading
  loadModels();
  // pause P5's update loop until the video is ready ('play' event)
  text("loading models", width * 0.5, height * 0.5);
  noLoop();
  
}

function loadModels(){
  Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
  ])
  // noLoop() was called in setup, pausing draw() while we load, we resume here once models are loaded
  .then(loop);
}
// make draw async to await faceapi results
async function draw(){
  const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(captureElement, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
  const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
  // render capture
  image(capture, 0, 0);
  
  // optional if mouse pressed debug draw face api in p5.js canvas
  if(mouseIsPressed){
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(p5CanvasElement, resizedDetections);
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(p5CanvasElement, resizedDetections);
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(p5CanvasElement, resizedDetections);
  }
  // default draw curveVertex()
  else{
    // skip this frame if there are no detections
    if(resizedDetections.length == 0) return;
    
    // example getting all landmarks (connected)
    // const landmarkPositions = resizedDetections[0].landmarks.positions;

    // example getting a subset (e.g. getMouth(), getNose(), etc.)
    const landmarkPositions = getMouth(resizedDetections[0].landmarks.positions);
    
    stroke(255);
    beginShape();
    for(let i = 0 ; i < landmarkPositions.length; i++){
      const position = landmarkPositions[i];
      curveVertex(position.x, position.y);
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }
  
}

function getJawOutline(positions) {
  return positions.slice(0, 17);
}

function getLeftEyeBrow(positions) {
  return positions.slice(17, 22);
}

function getRightEyeBrow(positions) {
  return positions.slice(22, 27);
}

function getNose(positions) {
  return positions.slice(27, 36);
}

function getLeftEye(positions) {
  return positions.slice(36, 42);
}

function getRightEye(positions) {
  return positions.slice(42, 48);
}

function getMouth(positions) {
  return positions.slice(48, 68);
}
```

The code is commented and you can choose to draw positions for one section of the face (e.g. getMouth(), getNose(), etc.) or the whole face (albeit connecting face elements), though this could something you might want to explore (for example something like [Matty Mariansky's experiments](https://twitter.com/mmariansky/status/1314853445141180416/photo/1))

[image: Matty Mariansky experiment drawing a single black ribbon on a white background which is constraint to face landmark detection points]

Comment: Hi George thank you for your detailed response! Yes, I would like to experiment with curves and some custom shapes using the face coordinates rather than repeating the same `drawLandsmarks` task in p5js. I tried to put in `curveVertex(landmarkPositions[0].x, landmarkPositions[0].y);` in the `draw()` function but keep getting an error: "script.js:66 Uncaught ReferenceError: landmarkPositions is not defined at draw..." seems like `landmarkPositions` is not being recognised outside of the async function?

Comment: I didn't want to comment before, but that bit of the code looks a bit hacky (especially that `setInterval` part: very likely that will be out of sync with p5.js `draw()`). Maybe you get away by declaring `landmarkPositions` as a global variable (at the top of your code), then in `draw()` check that `landmarkPositions` isn't `null/undefined` first. (e.g. if(landmarkPositions){ beginShape()...`). Ideally you would cleanup (make draw() async and process faceapi data there).

Comment: @CocoYuan I've updated the answer above with a tested script which shows how to draw either all the landmark positions (commented out) or a subsection (nose, eye, mouth, etc.). Hope this helps. If this is the solution to your question please remember to [mark the answer with the green check mark](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)